# Cambiar color de borde de un textfield

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

quiero que el borde de mi textfield cambie cuando esta en modo oscuro o modo claro el móvil, tengo esto para cambiar todo lo demás de color pero no consigo cambiar el borde de color.

```
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
@State var color = Color.black.opacity(0.7)


var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        
        
        
        Text("Logueate a tu cuenta")
            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white: .black)
        
        TextField("Username")
            .padding()
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke(self.email != "" ? Color("Color") : self.color, lineWidth: 2))
            .padding(.top, 25)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso tienes nombres de colores en esta línea que no se sabe si es claro u oscuro:

```
Color("Color")
```

Lo que hice con tu código fue lo siguiente:

```
TextField("Username", text: $username)
         .padding()
         .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke(self.email != "" ? Color.red : .white, lineWidth: 2))
         .padding(.top, 25)
```

Cambié esto:

```
  Color("Color")
```

por esto:

```
  Color.red
```

Entonces, cuando el correo sea vacío se debe pintar blanco:

```
var email: String = ""
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando el correo no sea vacío se debe pintar rojo:

```
var email: String = "a"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]